# sort_values() got multiple values for argument 'axis'

Tags: sorting, pandas-groupby, using

sort_values() got multiple values for argument 'axis'

I am trying to sort this series using sort_values

```
Item               Per Capita GSDP (Rs.)
Andhra_avg                        102803
Arunachal_avg                     100745
Assam_avg                        55650.6
Bihar_avg                        30030.6
Chattisgarh_avg                  82046.7
Gujrat_avg                        128755
Himachal_avg                      126650
Jharkhand_avg                      56385
Jammu_avg                        73422.8
Karnataka_avg                     128959
Kerala_avg                        139140
MP_avg                           61122.2
Maharashtra_avg                   133512
```

my code:

```
dfGDP_percapita.sort_values("Item", axis = 0, ascending = True, inplace = True, na_position ='first')
```

Expected result should give "`Per Capita GSDP (Rs.)`" in the decreasing order with Nan on top

Comment: Your code works when replicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to

`dfGDP_percapita.sort_values("Item", inplace=True, na_position ='first')`

Some of the arguments are by default - I'm not sure why the error occurs, but my code works like this.